# How to track cause of unexpected lighting changes?

Tags: philips-hue, smart-lights

I'm using a Philips Hue system with lights in my living room and bedroom. I'm using a v2.0 bridge that integrates with Apple Homekit, and I use a mix of triggers in both the Hue app and Homekit routines.

Lately I've been having a problem where I get woken up at night because some of my lights turn on unexpectedly. I don't have any timers that would trigger in the wee hours of the morning. How can I track down what is causing my lights to turn on? Is there any kind of tool that records which apps/events are generating events to change the lighting?

Comment: split the problem into sections ..... start by disconnecting the system from the internet and observing the result

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to get some info from your bridge.

When an app sends commands to the bridge, it uses a unique id.  A whitelist of these ids is kept in the bridge, along with the time each id was created and the last time it was used. Ideally, it also contains the name of the app, but some developers put some other word in the place they're supposed to put the app name.

Examining this list might tell you what's controlling your lights, and you can delete an id that you suspect is causing you problems. Note that the times for creation and last use are in UTC, not your local timezone.

To see the list:

Go to this page and go through the tutorial (it's just one page and doesn't require any programming ability).

https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2

Using the tool from that tutorial, enter

/api/yourid/config

(where yourid is the id you just created in the tutorial) in the URL box and click GET.  Scroll down thru the response to where it says "whitelist".

To delete an id, enter

/api/yourid/config/whitelist/badid

(where badid is the id you want to delete) and click DELETE

Also, you can enter

/api/yourid/schedules

and click GET to check if there are any schedules stored in the bridge

Comment: I'm definitely going to try this.